# Matchings between 2 or more equal size sets

Tags: math, combinations

Suppose I have 2 equal size sets {1,2,3,4} and {a,b,c,d}.  I want to count all possible matchings between these 2 sets:

```
{1a,2b,3c,4d}
{1a,2b,3d,4c}
{1a,2c,3b,4d}
{1a,2c,3d,4b}
{1a,2d,3b,4d}
{1a,2d,3d,4b}
{1b,2a,3c,4d}
{1b,2a,3d,4c}
{1b,2c,3a,4d}
{1b,2c,3d,4a}
...
```

Order within the matchings does not matter (these also are sets).

My question is what formula calculates the number of possible matchings between these 2 sets.  Also, what would the formula be if I want to count matchings across n equal size sets, instead of just 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without duplicates, think of it as creating 4 compound elements. For each of the elements from set 1, pair it with an element from set 2. As the order of the 4 compound elements doesn't matter, then we can arbitrarily pick an order from elements from set 1 and stick with it, because if we were to permute that order, we'd be able to rearrange that result and generate the same thing with the arbitrary order.

So we have to fill in these 'slots' from set 2:

```
(1_, 2_, 3_, 4_)
```

For the first slot how many possibilities do you have? You can pick any of the elements of set 2, so you have 4. What about second item from set 2? Now you only have 3 possibilities left.

Keep going and you get:

```
4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 4! = 24
```

More generally, if you have `n` equal sets each of size `m`, you have:

```
(m!)^(n-1)
```

Comment: Or alternatively: for each combination of set 1 you have all the possible combinations of set 2 --> m! combinations of set 1 * m! combinations of set 2

Comment: Exponent in general case should be one less, `(m!)^(n-1)`, as consistent with the case of two sets.

Comment: This is wrong, as the original question stated that the order should not matter in the result set. Thus, the elements of the first set should not be permuted (as this permutation does not cause a difference), causing the exponent in the final expression to be lower, and resulting in (m!)^(n-1) as stated in hardmath's comment.

Comment: @elias: oh I did not notice/understand that part of the problem. will update answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the order does not matter in the result set, you can rephrase your question as: if I use a fix ordering of the first set {1, 2, 3, 4} - let's say the naturally ordered list [1, 2, 3, 4] -, how many different lists can be produced by adding one element from the second set {a, b, c, d} to each element of the list?

Well, the element chosen to be in pair with element 1 of the ordered list made from the first set can be anything from set 2, giving 4 possibilities. No matter, which one is chosen, there are 3 others left to be paired with element 2, and so on, giving us the final answer of 4!=24.

The formula for 2 sets with the size of m is m!.

For the more general case of n sets with length m is (m!)^(n-1), and the thought behind this is the same: because the final answer is considered to be a set, the order in it does not matter, so we can fix the order of elements in the first set, but use any permutation for the other n-1 sets, which each have m! different permutations. Every selection can be done independently, resulting that we should just multiply these.

Answer (score -1):

The formula to calculate the number of possible ways to combine these 2 sets is: 4 elevated 4^4.  (for 2 equals sets it could be n^n, being n the size of the sets)
And for n equals sets, the formula it should be: n^((n-1)*n)
I hope it would help you.
Cheers!